# Javascript: Display the content of a line knowing its number

Tags: javascript, error-handling, line

I'm working on a JavaScript application and I'm trying to fix an error, but I can't find it. Here's what I have.

```
 function my_function (txt) {
    try {
        return eval('('+ txt + ')');
    }
    catch(e) {
      alert(e.lineNumber);
      return eval(txt);
    }
```

I'm passing the content of a file to the function, and it seems like there is an issue in this file. The problem is this line

```
          alert(e.lineNumber);
```

always returns the same number even when I add lines at the beginning of the file so I want to make sure I'm editing the right line. For that I want it to show the content of the line that contains the error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can print stacktrace using e.stack

```
....
catch(e) {
      alert(e.lineNumber);
      console.log(e.stack)
      return eval(txt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two cases:
    - if it is a syntax error, then the error will be reported as the location of the "eval" call that triggered it (not a location in the "source" file),
    - if it is a semantic error (it parsed but failed at run time), then take a look at http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/ to get some ideas on cross-browser stack dumps.

To debug the first case, you'll probably have to capture the file contents and try parsing it on its own (maybe use node or jsl).

I don't quite know what you are trying to do, but I have to say the code sample raises some questions (why eval not JSON.parse, why read the file then eval instead of including it and calling a function, what is with the second eval).

Answer (score 0):

Capture the text of the script, if necessary use `console.log (txt)` and copy paste the output into a file. Put a `<script>` at the top of that file and `</script>` at the bottom. Make the file name end in `.html`. Now double click that file icon. This will launch your browser which will read the script and output any syntax errors to the browser console showing the line number at which they occur.